# Center Text below an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-xml

How would I put a `textview` below an `imageview` so that the `text` is centered? If I use the `relative layout`, the only way is `android:layoutBelow` but you can't align to the center of the `imageview` as you can align to `right` or `left` of the image. Unless I have missed something

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comments I have a better understanding of what you are trying to accomplish. This uses an extra view but allows you to group the textview to the imageview.

RelativeLayout in the upper Left:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- place this layout anywhere and the imageview and textview will follow. -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RelativeLayout in the center of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- place this layout anywhere and the imageview and textview will follow. -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

RelativeLayout in the Bottom Right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <!-- place this layout anywhere and the imageview and textview will follow. -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:text="TextViewTextViewTextViewTextViewTextView" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView1"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

As you can see anywhere you place the inner RelativeLayout the ImageView and TextView follow.

Comment: Thank you but this Relative view is fixing the location on top left of the screen. I dont want it that way

Comment: You are missing the point. Place the Relative layout where ever you want it and your imageview and text will follow correctly. Where do you want it placed and I will adjusted it to show you how it works.

Comment: can you adjust it to be in the center of the screen ? I would like to better understand your solution

Comment: Adjustments have been made. I have provided three examples.

Comment: If you're going to group the image and text like that, you could just use a vertical LinearLayout and have both the text and image use `layout_gravity="center_horizontal"`. It would be more efficient that way.

Comment: @Karakuri That makes a lot of sense, not sure why I didn't think of it.

Answer (score 1):

Try declaring your textview like so:

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_align="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:layout_below="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" />
```

Comment: This works when the text is less than the width of the image.If it is greater then gets splitted into multi-line.  +1 for getting half working :)

Comment: Then you need to add these properties also. i.e. `android:singleLine="true"` and `android:ellipsize="end"`

Comment: That didnt fix the problem, all what it did was truncating the text by putting .......

Answer (score 0):

This will solve both your problems reading at the comment of the `Text length`, use `android:ems` in text which define the basic length of it

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="0dp"
android:layout_align="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:layout_alignRight="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:layout_below="@+id/id_of_imageview"
android:gravity="center_horizontal" 
android:ems="10" />
```